# dojo.string is undefined

Tags: dojo

I am reading the The Definitive Guide for DOJO.  I get this error when I try to execute:

```
dojo.string.pad("", 5); // "00000"
```

This does not work on Firebug or a separate code.  The example provided in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/string.html also gives the same error.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks Mahesh.

Comment: Which version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: for the TDG example i am using src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js".  For the dojo example at The  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/string.html, it uses <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo is organized into smaller modules. They must be loaded before using them, otherwise an error like:  `dojo.string is undefined` results. `dojo.require()` loads a module:

```
dojo.require('dojo.string');
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    console.log(dojo.string.trim(dojo.byId("foo").innerHTML));
});
```

I have fixed the Dojo 1.6 example you linked to in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4050974).

Dojo: TDG explains `dojo.require` in more detail in [A minimalist application harness example](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596516482/toolkit_overview.html#a_minimalist_application_harness_exa) and [Managing Source Code with Modules](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596516482/language_and_browser_utilities.html#managing_source_code_with_modules)

Finally, you should familiarize yourself with [Dojo AMD](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modules/), which replaces dojo.require.

Comment: This works fine.  But however there is a version of dojo (I dont know the version, I only have the folders, not the download zip) i have which i am able to make the TDG example work WITHOUT the dojo.require.  But it does not work for the dojotoolkit example.  I dont know how.  But I am good.  I will try to familiarize myself with AMD.

Comment: @user1071179: You can get the version with `dojo.version` Also if `dojo.string` was already dojo.required by another module you can get away without requiring it (one reason AMD is better)

Comment: dojo version is 1.4.3.  Ok.  Thanks for your responses Leftium.  Greatly appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is accurate. You may need to assign the returned value of the `string.pad` to some other variable.

```
var a = dojo.string.pad("0", 5);
```